# LESS styles: Comma-separated div's nested within media query not applying

Tags: html, css, nested, less, stylesheet

I'm super excited for my FIRST POST on Stack Overflow. It's been a long time coming!

A question: In the code below, the settings for .1, .2, etc. aren't applying. Here's my code:

LESS CODE:

```
@screen-lg-min: 1200px;
#laurels {

text-align:center;
margin: 0 auto;

@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
    width: 930px;

    .1, .2, .3, .4, .5 {
        width: 165px;
        height: 76px;
        padding: 0 5px;
    }               
}
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="laurels">
    <div class="lorel 1">
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp), a class name cannot start with a number.  So if you changed your

`.1, .2, .3` etc to

`.one, .two, .three` etc.  It will work.

Of course, the change must include the class declaration on your div.

`<div class="lorel one">`

Alternatively, if you prefer to use the numbers, simply prepend some text like so:

`.style_1, .style_2, .style_3`

Comment: Hi Chris, I tried this and it's still not working. The divs read <div class="lorel one"> and the rule reads .one, .two, .three, .four, .five {

Comment: Fixed! The issue was a conflicting CSS selector, which I didn't previously see because the classes were numbered. Thanks all!